# Starting ingredients for perpetual pit of snakes

Tags: science-based, biology, dungeons

I want to ensure that my burial tomb is guarded by a pit of snakes for all the ages, similar to that featured in Indiana Jones (Raiders of the Lost Ark). Initially, I thought I could have an ecosystem of snakes where larger species ate smaller species, but there would reach a point where the food supply would truncate and the species upstream on the food chain would be affected.

### Question

Working backwards, if I want a pit that is perpetually filled with snakes, what starting ingredients do I need to include at time of burial?

**Further clarifications**

- Time frame: needs to be viable for thousands of years
- Closed off, it's a sealed, self-contained pit (possibly with tiny vents for oxygen)

Comment: I think an ecosystem of snakes having a snake-only food chain could work, the smaller snakes would just have to multiply at a much quicker rate than the larger ones - which could be explained by natural selection (if 5 snakes get eaten, the species must create >5 snakes to last until procreation). Then I guess the question is what do the smallest snakes eat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Let the snakes pick.**

Find a cave that is already full of year round snakes.  Then get buried in there.  If the snakes are not ever leaving, the food will have to come to them.  A good option is bats, which are tasty and which come and go from caves.  So you could use

*THE CAVE OF THE HANGING SNAKES!*

[image]

https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/cave-of-the-hanging-snakes

> In addition to the swarms of bats and dangling serpents, there is also
> a flooded portion of the cave that houses blind albino crustaceans.
> It’s possible that this is the creepiest cave in the world. Or at
> least the one that most resembles a Dungeons and Dragons setting.

Many bats, and the snakes that eat them actually living in the ceiling.  Probably some wind up on the floor too.  I suspect the bat biomass also supplies the albino crustaceans.  Would it be excessive to have a giant [Olm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olm) be the apex predator?  No, I think that would be very appropriate.